# Creating checklist in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, checklist

Is it possible to create checklist in sharepoint 2013 which has some sort of tracking mechanism that tracks time (how  long did one take to finish the checklist)

Answer (score 0):

You could create workflow which will be triggered by item modified, when item(status column) complete, calculated the total time Current Time minus Created Time.

[Creating a workflow by using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo)

[image]

Comment: I am new to sharepoint and workflows. How many workflow do you think I need to create. The project I am working on is that managers would assign employees tasks in groups. Employees would then have to  go to sharepoint site, complete the checklist. Whoever finishes the checklist first would win. So how many workflows would be needed. I am confused as to how to go about this

Comment: Just one workflow, if each checklist represents a listitem in SharePoint list.

Comment: How do i go about the workflow. should I first choose if any value equals value (let says if status equals completed) then find interval between dates. I know workflow doesn't have then so how do i implement this ? can you help me write the workflow. Because i saw that sharepoint workflow doesn't have then. so i don't know how to write this. @Lee_MSFT

Comment: I also want to be able to send email to the users once the workflow is completed adding the time in the email?        @Lee_MSFT